# Spring4 + and Hibernate 4 Transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb, transactional

Using spring 4.0.6.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final and hsqldb 2.3.2. My integration test looks like the following;

```
 @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public final void testDuplicateItems() {
    final ServerEntity serverEntity1 = new ServerEntity("DuplicateItem");

    opService.save(serverEntity1);
    opService.save(serverEntity1);
}
```

This works as expected. However, when I run my standalone java component i can save the first item, the second item which is a duplicate is not saved but Im unable to catch the exception. Here is the log file

```
 WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 23505
2014-08-27 14:52:06,843  ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; UK_NFU7LXMMDFVIR1WD08662085N table: SERVERENTITY
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_NFU7LXMMDFVIR1WD08662085N]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:161)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:681)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:563)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.opserver.simpleapp.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:60)
    at com.opserver.simpleapp.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:37)
    ... 6 more
```

Both the service and dao implementations have @Transactional at class level. I've a component class that is calling the service class, this component class is not transactional! The component class prints a response, does the session need to be flushed here?

Need to figure out why the save method in the dao is not throwing the exception, I can actually see it an id being created and then rolled back.

J

My component class is very basic;

```
boolean isValid = opServerService.loadXMLFile("Server.xml");

    try{

    if (isValid) {
        System.out.println("Entity has been added");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Entity has not been added");
    }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("that was a focked up");
    }
```

The problem is that "Entity has been added" gets printed to console and then I see the above error in console.

DAO looks like this

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public final void save(final ServerEntity serverEntity) throws DataIntegrityViolationException {
        LOGGER.debug(">>start(serverEntity=" + serverEntity + ")");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(serverEntity);
        this.getCurrentSession().save(serverEntity);
    }
```

Service method with @Transactional at class level, looks like this

```
@Override
    public final void save(ServerEntity serverEntity) {
        opServerDao.save(serverEntity);
    }
```

And Component looks like this

```
@Component
public class AddCommand implements Command {

    @Autowired
    OpService opService;

    public AddServerCommand() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(String[] options) {

        try{
         boolean isValid = opService.save("Server.xml");
        if (isValid) {
            System.out.println("Entity has been added");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entity has not been added");
        }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception found");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should catch your exception in the component that's calling the service.

Comment: Updated the question, added Exception to validate what kind of exception is being thrown, but loadXML is not throwing an exception.

Comment: where are you calling your service method in component? can you post the code.

Comment: so you are not calling opService.save in AddCommand, if you feel you don't need @transactional at service layer, then remove it and catch the exception at service layer. you should catch the exceptions outside the transaction boundaries.

Comment: Here is the sequence of calls. Component class(non-transactional) invokes -> opService (OpServiceImplementation is transactional at class level) invokes -> calls DAO class (transactional at class level). In my component class I can see isValid is being returned as true so msg is printed. Then the error appears! Does the session need to be flushed in order for the commit exception to be thrown earlier?

Comment: your component looks incorrect, how can you pass a string to save? please post the correct code and see what can be done to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, was missing  from the applicationContext.xml. The wrapped try/catch around the opService now catches the exception. Need to implement my own custom exception handler but for now at least I know the component class is handling the exception which is being thrown from the service class.

Thanks for your help.

J